# How do links and scaling work together in docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's my understanding of docker compose:

- You can "scale" a service to run it in multiple containers at once.
- If you link service A to service B, service A has access to a container running service B.

Is my understanding correct, and if so, where does a link connect if there are multiple containers running the service?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First of all I would clarify that, by default, with or without linking a container with other, all container has visibility to other containers running in the same host (using the container IP). You can change this behavior using the `icc=true` flag in docker daemon.

In respect of the links with docker-compose, these are generated when the container with the links are created. Let's see it with an example. Using this docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  build: .
  command: python app.py
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
  links:
   - redis
redis:
  image: redis
```

After running `docker-compose up -d` the `web_1` container is linked with the container with `redis_1`:

```
        (...)
        "Links": [
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_1/compose_redis_1",
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_1/redis",
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_1/redis_1"
    ], (...)
```

Now we want to scale the `redis` service using `docker-compose scale redis=2`. After running it (and create a new container `redis_2`), the links in `web_1` keeps unchanged.

```
        (...)
        "Links": [
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_1/compose_redis_1",
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_1/redis",
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_1/redis_1"
    ], (...)
```

It is needed to stop, remove and run `web_1` to see these links created:

```
docker-compose stop web
docker-compose rm web
docker-compose run -d web
docker inspect compose_web_run_2
(...)        "Links": [
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_run_2/compose_redis_1",
        "/compose_redis_2:/compose_web_run_2/compose_redis_2",
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_run_2/redis",
        "/compose_redis_1:/compose_web_run_2/redis_1",
        "/compose_redis_2:/compose_web_run_2/redis_2"
    ],(...)
```

And the `/etc/hosts` of `web_1` container:

```
172.17.0.24 7be2dabea910
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.21 compose_redis_1 8a1297a5b3e4
172.17.0.23 compose_redis_2 069dd46836aa
172.17.0.21 redis 8a1297a5b3e4 compose_redis_1
172.17.0.21 redis_1 8a1297a5b3e4 compose_redis_1
172.17.0.23 redis_2 069dd46836aa compose_redis_2
```

**So to generate the new links, you is is needed to stop, remove, and run again the container.**

Comment: So if service A is linked to service B, service A has access to ALL instances of service B?

Comment: Using the container's IPs has always access, but if you the access as with `--link` option (i.e.: with entries in /etc/hosts, global environment variables...) you would need to recreate service A container.

Comment: That's not my question. Is service A linked to ALL Instances of service B, or ONE instance of service B?

Comment: It's linked with ALL instances of service B, but each with different alias (e.g.: redis_1 and redis_2). Check my answer to see the `/etc/hosts` of the example

Comment: It would be great if this were updated to reflect version 2 of the docker-compose yaml format. Notably the depends_on: key as opposed to links.

Comment: So if I want to use link to ref a web container in a nginx container,  I should use `web_1`, `web_2` rather than `web` ? There is no load balancing ?

Comment: links are no longer handled using `/etc/hosts` entries. They're created using an internal DNS reference. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2172#issuecomment-256317617